# Can I vertically scale an Amazon instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

Is it possible? According to Amazon, *Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling* uses Horizontal scaling:

> You can also use Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling for dynamic scaling of EC2 instances in order to automatically increase the number of Amazon EC2 instances during demand spikes to maintain performance and decrease capacity during lulls to reduce costs.

I found no reference to vertical scaling, by changing each instance specifications instead of adding or removing them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To vertically scale an individual AWS EC2 instance up or down the instance has to be stopped, then the instance size changed, then restarted. This is due to the fact that Amazon has to often move the VM to a different piece of hardware with the available resources for the size change. Also, operating systems and software don't generally handle the sudden appearance of extra RAM or CPU cores very well.

Amazon does not provide a service for automatically scaling instances vertically, only horizontally, because horizontal scaling is the only type of scaling that doesn't incur down time.

Comment: To clarify: Changing instance type **always** changes host computers. Each host computer only runs one type of instance.

Comment: Looks like this new feature helps to vertically scale up or down. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/aws-ops-automator-v2-features-vertical-scaling-preview/

Comment: I think 'fargate' does that for you.

Comment: @bitsabhi no it doesn't.

Comment: Unfortunately - this is still in preview ( 10-AUG-2020) https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/aws-ops-automator-v2-features-vertical-scaling-preview/

Comment: Is OpsAutomator still Preview state ?

Comment: why can you simply spin up a larger instance, add it to the same subnet behind your ASG/NLB, then let it go all run a that point our bring down the smaller instances?

Comment: @mike01010 You can certainly do that, but that isn't really vertically scaling an instance, it is replacing it with a different instance. It also can't be done with automatically, it is a manual process. The question is about Autoscaling.

Comment: @MarkB glad you could decipher that gibberish i just wrote - need to proof more.  
Ok , so it's not autoscaling as a function of what a cloud provider may offer - but it can be considered an autoscaling implementation if automated - homegrown of sorts.

Comment: @mike01010 Feel free to post that as a separate answer to this question if you feel it is a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon ECS enables you to control the usage of swap memory space on your Linux container instances at the container level. Using a per-container swap configuration, each container within a task definition can have swap enabled or disabled, and for those that have it enabled, the maximum amount of swap space used can be limited. For example, latency-critical containers can have swap disabled, whereas containers with high transient memory demands can have swap turned on to reduce the chances of out-of-memory errors when the container is under load.

Read more here, [Managing Container Swap Space](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-swap)

The following is an example showing the JSON syntax:

additional configurable knob that allows us to configure a max swap size of 512 MB with an average aggressiveness (swappiness accepts an integer between 0 and 100).

```
{
    "family": "mywebsite",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "cpu": "256",
    "memory": "512",
    "requiresCompatibilities": ["EC2"], 
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "mywebsite-nginx",
            "image": "nginx:latest",
            "essential": true,
            "cpu": 128,
            "memory": 256,
            "memoryReservation": 128,
            "linuxParameters": {
                "maxSwap": 512,
                "swappiness": 50
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Alternatively do read about AWS opsworks, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinglayers-ecscluster.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Amazon EC2 instances can be scaled vertically. For that Spin up a new instance with large configuration than the one you are currently running. Pause this instance and detach the root ebs volume from the server and discard. Then stop your live old instance and detach its root volume and note the unique device ID and attach that root volume to your new instance with large configuration and then start it.